# Switching OleDB to SQLClient yields Incorrect syntax near '?' error

Tags: xsd, oledb, upgrade, sqlclient

All,

I have an old .Net web application and I am trying to replace the provider from "System.Data.OleDb" to "System.Data.SqlClient" as SQL 2016 no longer supports OLEDb.

However I get the following error in a temporary file when running the application:
    **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '?'.**

After some research, I found out that "?" is the OleDB way to represent parameters in the .xsd file. My question is as follows:

*What is the simplest, quickest and most efficient way to convert an OLEDB connection to a SQLClient one? Can I simply replace the parameters in xsd? Can I update to .xsd to point to the new SQLClient connection?*

Comment: What do you mean by SQL 2016 does not support OleDB? As far as I can determine on my installation it works just fine. However... parameters in OleDb are positional rather than named. i.e. you add parameters to the OleDbCommand in the order in which they occur in the SQL whereas you can add named SqlClient parameters in any order. Without code samples it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: @Ciaran: Thanks for your response. This is what I am getting from IT support. If you are telling me they're wrong, I will certainly take a look.